# Install Python 2.7.8 (64-bit) without replacing existing Python27 installation

Tags: python, windows

on Windows 7, is there a mean to install Python 2.7.8 (64-bit) without replacing existing Python27 (64-bit) installation?

Comment: My problem is that python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi instalaltion replaces previous 2.7.0 version even when I indicate another installation directory and that if I first install 2.7.8 version and then 2.7.0, both versions are installed but they contains both 2.7.8 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am agree with Burhan Khalid but pay attention to PATH.

Indeed, if you execute .py with double click windows take the Python executable defined in PATH variable.

If you use Command Line Interface to execute Python file you will not have any problems.

It is due to python27.dll file. When we install Python2.7.x it use the dll file located in C:\Windows\System32\ (C:\Windows\SysWOW64 in 64 bits plateforme)

Please, follow these steps:
You must to install Python 2.7.0 in C:\Python270, copy Python27.dll in C:\Python270\path folder (you must create path folder).
You must to install Python 2.7.8 in C:\Python278, copy new Python27.dll in C:\Python278\path folder (you must create path folder).

In each Python folder (Python270 and Python278) you can create an run.bat file and append this content :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;Path
python.exe
```

And you try execute batch file and check python version.
Can you confirm me if it's works ?

Comment: Thanks.
for the path, I shall use a link that will indicate the Python version to use.
My problem is to install both Python 2.7.8 and Python 2.7.0. On Windows 7. With https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi, previous 2.7.0 version is replaced even when I indicate another installation directory.

Comment: Because the PATH variable is updated. With CLI try : 
`C:\Python27\python.exe` and `import sys` then `print (sys.version)` and you must try also
`C:\Python278\python.exe` and `import sys` then `print (sys.version)`.
It should display you `2.7.0` and `2.7.8`

Comment: I made tests but nothing worked as you said :
1°) PATH does not seem to be updated by installations.
2°) when I install Python 2.7.0 and then 2.7.8, 2.7.0 is replaced even when I change destination directory.

Comment: 3°) when I install Python 2.7.8 and then 2.7.0 in different directories, both are available. When I launch d:\Python\Python278\python.exe, its version is 2.7.8, that is correct. When I launch d:\Python\Python270\python.exe, its version is 2.7.8, that is not correct, it should be 2.7 (2.7 is the indicated version when 2.7.0 version is the only installation of Python 2.7)

Comment: I think I have found your problem. I edit my answer to be more clear.

Comment: It's effectively Python27.dll located in C:\Windows\System32\ (even in 64 bits plateforme when you installed 64-bit version) that makes the problem. I don't try your idea to make a .bat to modify PATH because I think that it's will work only one time (if you put Path at the end of PATH, previous modifications should be used before last modification).
I moved python27.dll to C:\Python27X with python.exe that uses it and it solved the problem. You can launch any version, you just have to indicate the full path or to make a link to the selected version path.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wonder why installations put python27.dll in C:\Windows\System32\ . That is not usefull and prevent from using several 2.7 subcersions.
In fact, problem comes from installations that should not put python27.dll in C:\Windows\System32\.

Comment: Putting DLL in C:\Windows\System32\ was used but it leads to "DLL Hell". I don't know what is the interest to do that in Python installations.

Comment: I don't know why Python installer put DLL in Windows. I prefered it in PythonXX folder.
If my answer is good, can you validate it please ?

Comment: Installations should ask if we want to remove previous versions and  should permit to install several (sub-)versions simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I think also installation can be portable. This way allow to use several versions without conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this is to install it in a different location than the default `C:\Python27`.

You can set the install path in the Windows installer.

Comment: Thanks. My problem is that with https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi, previous 2.7.0 version is replaced even when I indicate another installation directory. if I first install 2.7.8 version and then 2.7.0, both versions are installed and they contains 2.7.8 version. Did I miss something ?